# WooCommerce Shop Duplicates Products on Display

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, infinite-scroll, product

After Installing infinite scrolling plugin, I have noticed some products are displayed more than once and some are not displayed at all. Sometimes I had to refresh the page to display the non displayed ones.

Can anyone help me on this? I really don't want to lose the infinite scroll functionality.

Website URL: www.TechEmirates.ae

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the plugin with another one that is compatible with your theme, use [YITH Infinite Scrolling](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-infinite-scrolling/)

it has good compatibility in general
are you sure that your theme does not have infinite scroll functionality built in? explore your theme options one more time

Comment: Hi Yahya! Thanks for your reply... I am actually using exactly the same plugin, my theme doesn't have built-in infinite scrolling functionality.

Comment: I think you got the idea, the plugin is not compatible with your theme, so you have to look for another, I think you might have to purchase a paid one.
actually I checked your website and everything seems just great, maybe you have to browse your website using another browser or PC